# Spring Web Flow - store request param across views(jsf pages)

Tags: jsf, request, store, spring-webflow, param

Have transition configuration for Spring Web Flow:

```
<transition on="getFiles">
    <evaluate expression="searchService.getFiles(flowScope.searchCriteria, requestParameters.fileId)"
     result="viewScope.file" result-type="dataModel"/>
</transition>
```

It's needed to invoke `searchService.getFiles(flowScope.searchCriteria, requestParameters.fileId)` method in two cases:

**1.** retrieve files (occurred on `1.xhtml`)
**2.** sort files (occurred on `2.xhtml`)

Problem is that, when sorting(step 2) files, `requestParameters.fileId` is lost.

Is it way to store `fileId` param cross `1.xhtml` and `2.xhtml` views?

Answer (score 0):

Dont request the fileId attribute by the requestParameters.  The requestParameters object is basically the request attributes.  You can observe that you set the file as viewScope.file.  That means that anywhere within the view you can access the file accordingly.  Does viewScope.file.fileId exist?

The request is lost after the first transition, an alternative is you can try setting it into the flashScope.

Update based on your comment.  Try setting it into the flash/viewScope first.

You can do it like this

```
<transition on="getFiles">
    <set var="flashScope.fileId" value="requestParameters.fileId"/>
    <evaluate expression="searchService.getFiles(flowScope.searchCriteria, requestParameters.fileId)"
     result="viewScope.file" result-type="dataModel"/>
</transition>
```

Comment: viewScope.file is list of files,that id's are not connected to requestParameters.fileId.So i will try flashScope.

Comment: thanks for edition, one more issue- my JSF version is 1.2 ,is flashScope applied for it?

Comment: Flashscope is a spring-webflow-2 property.  If you cant access flashscope you can manage it under the flowScope (flowScope spans the lifetime of the entire flow)